# Dependent module siblings know each others?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angularjs, and wondering how the following code can actually work without issues. The main question here is that when the module "myControllersModule" is created, it does not list "myServicesModule" as one of its dependencies. But when it create the controller "logController", the injectcted "logservice" argument can be resolved without a problem. Is this because all "sibling modules" listed in the dependency array of the "top-level" module "myApp" somehow automatically know each others?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head><title>My Test</title></head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module("myServicesModule", [])
        .factory("logService", function() {
            var messageCount = 0;
            return {
                log: function(msg) {
                    console.log("(LOG + " + messageCount++ + ") " + msg);
                }
            };
        });

    angular.module("myControllersModule", [])
        .controller("logController", function($scope, logService) {
            $scope.logit = logService.log;
        });

    angular.module("myApp", ['myControllersModule','myServicesModule']);
</script>


<body ng-controller="logController">
<button ng-click="logit('XYZ')">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject dependencies at controller level also if you want to use service--

```
angular.module("myControllersModule", ['myServicesModule'])
        .controller("logController", function($scope, logService) {
            $scope.logit = logService.log;
        });
```

You will be able to use service but while writing unit test cases, it will throw an error because of absence of myServicesModule in controller